# Gitstats error on Windows

Tags: git

I am trying to use Gitstats on Windows
I have installed Python, gnuplot and git. I have cloned the gitstats repository from Github
I am trying the below command
    python gitstats  
It gives me error:

> File "gitstats", line 58
>         print '>> ' + ' | '.join(cmds),
>                 ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: You’ve installed Python 3. It expects Python 2.

Comment: I have installed 2.6 and Gnuplot 4.0  <code> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GitStats\git-stats", line 1162, in ?
    g.run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "D:\GitStats\git-stats", line 1145, in run
    data.loadCache(cachefile)
  File "D:\GitStats\git-stats", line 98, in loadCache
    self.cache = pickle.load(f)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\pickle.py", line 1390, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python24\lib\pickle.py", line 872, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: 'x' </code>